# Difference between ∂w/∂x and ∂f/∂x

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If we have $w = f(x, y, z)$ and $z = g(x, y)$, how would I take the partial derivative of $w$ with respect to $x$?

Would it be $\frac{\partial w}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$?
But then what is the difference between $\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$? Are they not the same thing like they are in calc 1?

Comment: isn't that chain rule?

Comment: If $w=f(x,y,z)$, then $\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write 
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}\cdot\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x},
\end{align*}
you are dealing with the function
\begin{align*}
\varphi:(x,y)\rightarrow f(x,y,g(x,y)).
\end{align*}
A better expression would be 
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\partial\varphi}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}\cdot\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial x},
\end{align*}
or even better that
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\partial\varphi}{\partial x}=D_{1}f+D_{3}f\cdot\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial x}.
\end{align*}

Meanwhile, when you write
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x},
\end{align*}
you are dealing with the function 
\begin{align*}
(x,y,z)\rightarrow f(x,y,z)
\end{align*}
and you have labelled this function as $w$.

In short, there is some sort of composite of functions in the first one (to the third coordinate of $w$, or $f$) and the second one is merely the function $w$ (or $f$), so in two cases you are dealing with entirely two different functions.

Comment: But then is it true that the product of partial derivatives in the second term is 0?

Comment: No, in general they are not $0$. I can see why you are confused, the point is that, you should not merely use the notation $w$ for the first one, there is some sort of composite functions, using merely $w$ is extremely inaccurate and misleading.

Comment: So you mean that your statement with partial of w wrt x = partial of f wrt x only holds when we are considering the simple function that maps (x, y, z) -> f(x, y, z) where x y and z are all independent? Whereas in my case z depends on x and y and this simple equality is not true?

Comment: Okay, in some sense, your explanation goes through.